# Hosting - US vs Local?

Tags: web-hosting

I am making a website for a friend, located in the US. I am located in Europe.

Using HostGator I could host it for around 107 usd per year, while in my country it would only be 40 usd. Acccording to my experience, the local hosting service has no issues.

Is there a reason I should use US host instead of european?

Comment: You should be able to find something substantially less than that in the US.  There are several hosting companies with prices in the $1 to $3 per month range when you pre-pay for 2 or 3 years.  Just search for something like "shared hosting prices."

Comment: Thank you but pre paying for 2-3 years isn't an option right now. It will be a small website for now and we will see later if we want to go for a longer period.

Comment: You can find better deals than $107 a year even when you're paying for shorter periods of time though

Answer (score 1):

This depends somewhat on the purpose and complexity of the website, as well as where most of the customers are located.

Assuming the customers are located in the US, hosting the site in the US will provide a lower latency and likely higher bandwidth.  This could shave (roughly) about 100ms of the latency - this is not massive, but is more then implied because loading a web page requires multiple round trips (eg a minimum of 1 for SSL negotiation - although often more, 1 for the web page, and 1 for the images - so if the latency difference is 100ms, the minimum page load time goes up by 300ms by hosting it in Europe).   **You being in Europe would likely give you a different website experience to people in USA**

Also, generally the closer to the client, the greater the bandwidth available.  This is often due to better connectivity for closer devices, but also because tcp/ip takes latency into account to determine the maximum speed.   If the site is highly optimised this may not be a big deal though - but for sites with large images it can be significant.

I am very biased, but I perceive Hostgator as an average provider - middle of the range performance at a good price.   In the "middle-of-the-range" providers at these both the above pricepoints you are signalling that performance is of secondary concern - and it is quite possible the cheaper European hosting will outperform the Hostgator pricing (as an anecdote, I have servers in New Zealand, and host a number of sites for companies in Asia.  My servers performance often outshines closer providers even though there is an extra 150ms latency - but my servers are way more powerful and optimised - and the client sites benefit from the extra CPU)

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend some better hostings in the US? I know that I could "just google them", but being in Europe - I don't know the popular opinion on them. Me choosing HostGator just proves that.

Comment: Sorry, I cant really advise. I am passionate about doing my own hosting so I dont have a lot if ecperiences with other providers. Also I am as far from the US as you are!  (Also, I did not say Hostgator is bad - just they strike ne as average)